# Save resized images with Glide

Tags: android, resize, save, android-glide

Is possible save an image resized with glide in a file?
I' m using this code:

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(path)
    .override(600, 200) 
    .centerCrop() 
    .into(imageViewResizeCenterCrop);
```

How i can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible. I'm using a `SimpleTarget` (a [custom target](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets) in Glide parlance) descendant I created for this specific purpose. It's very simple to use. Here is the `Target` code:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import com.bumptech.glide.request.animation.GlideAnimation;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.SimpleTarget;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileTarget extends SimpleTarget<Bitmap> {
    public FileTarget(String fileName, int width, int height) {
        this(fileName, width, height, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70);
    }
    public FileTarget(String fileName, int width, int height, Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality) {
        super(width, height);
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.format = format;
        this.quality = quality;
    }
    String fileName;
    Bitmap.CompressFormat format;
    int quality;
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                bitmap.compress(format, quality, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                onFileSaved();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                onSaveException(e);
            }
    }
    public void onFileSaved() {
        // do nothing, should be overriden (optional)
    }
    public void onSaveException(Exception e) {
        // do nothing, should be overriden (optional)
    }

}
```

And here is how you would use it within your own example:

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(path)
    .asBitmap()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(new FileTarget(pathToDestination, 600, 200));
```

This code does not show the image on any view, it saves it directly to the destination.

Comment: @ArMo372 you're doing something wrong, or missing some step. If you post the pertinent code, I can try to help you.

Comment: @Loudenvier great answer, I also pass the ImageView target as argument if you want to set the image into an image view and save into a file too. https://gist.github.com/agustinsivoplas/7261d7316e854a66a547e17da02476c3 :)

Comment: I believe .asBitmap() is missing in your Glide call which would result "Cannot resolve method"

Comment: @abdfahim Wow! Sharp eyes... You've spotted the bug without a debugger (I'm getting rust in my "by hand" debugging skills). That's the problem alright! (in my production code the `asBitmap` is used, of course) Fixing the answer right now. Thank you.

Comment: @ArMo372 there was a bug in the "usage" code. A `asBitmap()` call was missing. The answer is now updated!

Comment: This is fantastic! I've been using BitmapFactory to post process a camera image, but without a LOT of work, cropping resulted in losing massive amounts of the image on newer devices due to the image dimensions (which I then cropped to 1024x1024). I'm using Glide elsewhere in project so this is perfect, simple, and probably much better on memory too! Thanks

Comment: @Loudenvier, use above code as  Glide
    Glide.with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(path)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(new FileTarget(pathToDestination, 600, 200));

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using custom bitmap transform

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(path)
            .bitmapTransform(new CropTransformation(this, 600, 200))
            .into(imageView);
```

Download [CropTransformation](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/glide/transformations/CropTransformation.java)

Inside

```
 public Resource<Bitmap> transform(Resource<Bitmap> resource, int outWidth, int outHeight) {`
```

Save `bitmap` before

```
 return BitmapResource.obtain(bitmap, mBitmapPool);
```

See all transformations [here](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)